# Can't get data from the sqlite android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

When the data pass to the database handler, there is a value which must match with the SQLite. But I still can't retrieve the data using cursor.

Here is the code of retrieving data.

```
public String getBusInfoDest (String destin) {

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

 Cursor cursor1 = db.query(TABLE_BUS, new String[] { KEY_ROUTE , KEY_DESTINATION , KEY_FEE , KEY_TYPE , KEY_VIA1 , KEY_VIA2 , KEY_VIA3 }, KEY_DESTINATION + "=?", new String[] { destin }, null, null, null, null );
 Cursor cursor2 = db.query(TABLE_BUS, new String[] { KEY_ROUTE , KEY_DESTINATION , KEY_FEE , KEY_TYPE , KEY_VIA1 , KEY_VIA2 , KEY_VIA3 }, KEY_VIA1 + "=?", new String[] { destin }, null, null, null, null );
 Cursor cursor3 = db.query(TABLE_BUS, new String[] { KEY_ROUTE , KEY_DESTINATION , KEY_FEE , KEY_TYPE , KEY_VIA1 , KEY_VIA2 , KEY_VIA3 }, KEY_VIA2 + "=?", new String[] { destin }, null, null, null, null );
 Cursor cursor4 = db.query(TABLE_BUS, new String[] { KEY_ROUTE , KEY_DESTINATION , KEY_FEE , KEY_TYPE , KEY_VIA1 , KEY_VIA2 , KEY_VIA3 }, KEY_VIA3 + "=?", new String[] { destin }, null, null, null, null );


 if (cursor1 != null ) {
     if  (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {

         String route = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROUTE));
         String destination = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESTINATION));
         String fee = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(KEY_FEE));
         String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE));
         String via1 = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA1));
         String via2 = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA2));
         String via3 = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA3));


         return "Route: " + route + "\n" + "Destination: " + destination + "\n" + "Fare: " + fee + "\n" + "Type: " + type + "\n"
                 + "Via: " + via1 + "\n" + "      " + via2 + "\n" + "      " + via3;
     }
 }
 else if (cursor2 != null ) {
         if  (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {

             String route = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROUTE));
             String destination = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESTINATION));
             String fee = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(KEY_FEE));
             String type = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE));
             String via1 = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA1));
             String via2 = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA2));
             String via3 = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA3));


             return "Route: " + route + "\n" + "Destination: " + destination + "\n" + "Fare: " + fee + "\n" + "Type: " + type + "\n"
                     + "Via: " + via1 + "\n" + "      " + via2 + "\n" + "      " + via3;
         }
 }
 else if (cursor3 != null ) {
        if  (cursor3.moveToFirst()) {

                 String route = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROUTE));
                 String destination = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESTINATION));
                 String fee = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(KEY_FEE));
                 String type = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE));
                 String via1 = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA1));
                 String via2 = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA2));
                 String via3 = cursor3.getString(cursor3.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA3));


                 return "Route: " + route + "\n" + "Destination: " + destination + "\n" + "Fare: " + fee + "\n" + "Type: " + type + "\n"
                         + "Via: " + via1 + "\n" + "      " + via2 + "\n" + "      " + via3;
             }
 }
 else if (cursor4 != null ) {
        if  (cursor4.moveToFirst()) {

                 String route = cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROUTE));
                 String destination = cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESTINATION));
                 String fee = cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex(KEY_FEE));
                 String type = cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE));
                 String via1 = cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA1));
                 String via2 = cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA2));
                 String via3 = cursor4.getString(cursor4.getColumnIndex(KEY_VIA3));


                 return "Route: " + route + "\n" + "Destination: " + destination + "\n" + "Fare: " + fee + "\n" + "Type: " + type + "\n"
                         + "Via: " + via1 + "\n" + "      " + via2 + "\n" + "      " + via3;
                }

 }

     return "No data";
```

}

The return value is also "No data" and only enter to the cursor1 if-else statement.

Thanks.

Comment: if you wish it to enter into all the cursors if conditions, then in that case remove the "elses", also create separate functions for all the cursors.

Comment: @Ratatatat Ratatouille: You should make your comment an answer.